# PHP - Calculate Array with Non Numeric Value

Tags: php, arrays, csv, numeric

From mycsv.csv
**$data[7]** has these:

```
4294967296/4294967296  
4294967296  
8589934592/8589934592
```

I want to calculate and put GB, so they become like this:

```
4GB/4GB  
4GB  
8GB/8GB
```

**What I did:**

```
<?php

$a = str_ireplace("/"," ",$data[7]);  
echo (floor($a/1000000000))."GB";
```

But it gives error for the ones that have `/`:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in... on line 45   4GB

...

Help Please... Thank you

---

Sorry, I think I describe it wrong.
So, I have a csv file with many data in it.

```
while (! feof($CSVvar)) {
        $data = fgetcsv($CSVvar, 1000, ",");
        if (! empty($data)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data[0]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data[7]; ?></td></tr>
```

will give among others:

**$data[7]**

4294967296/4294967296

then another

**$data[7]**

4294967296

and so on..

Comment: Showing a sample of the data structure might help to clarify. I think you are getting CSV data line-by-line in a loop with each iteration resulting in an array of data, and you are interested in index 7 of each array. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. (I edited my question. I think I wasn't clear at the beginning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `floor` a string like `4294967296 4294967296` after you do the `str_ireplace`. You will need a bit of looping for this but I have tried to make it as short as possible for you keeping it readable(hopefully).

So, split the string based on new lines so you would get each string in a separate array index.

Now, for each string of the form `x/y` or `x` itself, we split the string based on `/`. Now, we divide each number in the array by `1e9` to convert bytes to Giga bytes and implode them back with a `GB` suffix attached to it.

Finally, we collect these results in a new array and implode them back using a new line character.

```
<?php

$result = [];

foreach(explode("\n", $data[7]) as $str){
    $result[] = implode("GB/", array_map(fn($v) => floor($v / 1e9), explode("/", $str))). 'GB';
}

echo implode("\n", $result);
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/ITZLm)

Answer (score 1):

```
$data[7] = [
'4294967296/4294967296',
'4294967296',
'8589934592/8589934592',
];
foreach($data[7] as $data){
    $data_spilt = explode('/',$data);
    $strGb = [] ;
    foreach($data_spilt as $gb){
        $strGb[] = (floor($gb/1000000000))."GB";
    }
    echo implode('/',$strGb)."<br>";
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: It gives this error:
Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given in... on line 44

Comment: @Pekzz Maybe your `$data[7]` has a different value? [Working example](https://onecompiler.com/php/3zdvnr3vh).

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. I think I did not describe it well at the beginning. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).